# How to use sealed classes in Android using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, sealed-class

I am not able to understand how/when to use sealed classes in Android using Kotlin. I have read the docs but still I am getting confused about its structure and how to use it. It'd of great help if someone could help me understand this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Sealed classes** allow us to represent hierarchies in a more flexible way. It’s also more readable and is used for better state management.
Child-classes of Sealed class, can be of any type, like: data class, object class, any regular class, or even another sealed class.

This is how we define a sealed class in Android using Kotlin:

```
sealed class UiState {
    object Loading : UiState() 
    data class Success(val successMessage: String) : UiState()
    data class Error(val error: Throwable?) : UiState()
}
```

Let’s understand this part of the code:

**object Loading : UiState()** : declared this as an object, as we don’t need to know anything else at this stage.

**data class Success(val successMessage: String) : UiState()** : declared as data class, as we need the message when we got Success state.

**data class Error(val error: Throwable?)** : declared this as data class, as we need the Throwable when we got Error state.

Notice how we have used **object Loading : UiState()**. We are using the same sealed class name as the return type of “Loading” object.
This says, that the **“Loading” object belongs to “UiState” sealed class.**

This is same for **Success** and **Error** states as well.

We can then use this sealed class as the following:

```
fun observeUiStates(uiState: UiState) = when(uiState) {
    UiState.Loading -> println("Loading...Please wait.")
    is UiState.Success -> println(uiState.successMessage)
    is UiState.Error -> println(uiState.errorMessage)
}
```

In this aforementioned block of code we are passing the **UiState** sealed class as a parameter to **observeUiStates()** method and then by using **when** we are checking which is the current state of the app and then we will be handling the states accordingly.

Here for the sake of this example, I am just printing the result in the console.

Sealed classes, best work with **Model-View-Intent** pattern in Android by using **RxJava**.

By using them, we will now be able to **observe to the state changes.**

Whenever there is a new state of the app, this **observeUiStates()**  method will give us that specific state only.

To keep it simple for this specific example, I am calling this method from **main()**. See the code below:

```
fun main() {
    observeUiStates(UiState.Loading)
    observeUiStates(UiState.Success("The Ui has returned success state.”))
}
```

This will print the following in the console:

```
Loading...Please wait.
The Ui has returned success state.
```

Comment: Wonderful answer, and I've been using this. 2 recomendations: Have the Success state return your data `class Success<T>(val data: T)`, and also add a 4th case, a UiState.Empty.

Answer (score 0):

@Sayan answer is excellent

I use a slight variation in my apps especially when I load multiple things independently of each other. Example, from separate data sources.

Define a generic state sealed class

```
sealed class State<T> {
    class Loading<T> : State<T>()
    class Empty<T> : State<T>()
    data class Success<T>(val value: T) : State<T>()
    data class Error<T>(val message: String? = null) : State<T>()
}
```

And use it like so

```
var stateOne: State<List<User>> = State.Loading()
var stateTwo: State<List<Thing>> = State.Loading()

// loads data then assigns like
stateOne = State.Success(data goes here)
```

Hope this helps someone